# How to silence a program's output in command line without sudo access

Tags: ubuntu, command-line

I'm trying to prevent an executable program from printing anything to the terminal (to record program runtime for various programs without seeing their output which are intended to print to the terminal otherwise) without sudo access (/dev/null)

Is it possible?

Comment: What do you need sudo for? Every user can pipe to `/dev/null` - like: `echo asdf >/dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: @HerbertPoul I get permission denied whenever i use /dev/null (maybe because of limitations of the online ide i'm using itself or the ubuntu version it runs on), therefore i would like an alternative if i cannot get sudo access in it to hide program output to fit more information info in the terminal window

Comment: This sounds wrong, maybe you can check to see if `/dev/null` is indeed a valid block device, or a regular file.. it sounds like somebody broke something ️ see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146633/bash-dev-null-permission-denied

Comment: Otherwise, if it's just about not cluttering your terminal you could just as well pipe to some arbitrary file.. like `>/var/tmp/ignore.$$.log 2>&1`